# Interaction between pathos.ProcessingPool and pickle

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pickle, pathos

I have a list of calculations I need to run. I'm parallelizing them using

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
pool = ProcessingPool(nodes=7)
values = pool.map(helperFunction, someArgs)
```

`helperFunction` does create a class called `Parameters`, which is defined *in the same file* as

```
import otherModule
class Parameters(otherModule.Parameters):
    ...
```

So far, so good. `helperFunction` will do some calculations, based on the `Parameters` object, change some of its attributes, and finally store them using `pickle`. Here's the relevant excerpt of the helper function (from a different module) that does the saving:

```
import pickle
import hashlib
import os
class cacheHelper():

    def __init__(self, fileName, attr=[], folder='../cache/'):
        self.folder = folder

        if len(attr) > 0:
            attr = self.attrToName(attr)
        else:
            attr = ''
        self.fileNameNaked = fileName
        self.fileName = fileName + attr

    def write(self, objects):
        with open(self.getFile(), 'wb') as output:
            for object in objects:
                pickle.dump(object, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

when it gets to `pickle.dump()`, it raises an Exception which is hard to debug because the debugger wont step into the worker that actually faced that exception. Therefore I created a breakpoint right before the dumping happened, and manually entered that command. Here is the output:

```
>>> pickle.dump(objects[0], output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-4d2cbb7c63d1>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.dump(objects[0], output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1376, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 1203, in save_type
    StockPickler.save_global(pickler, obj)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 754, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Parameters'>: it's not found as __main__.Parameters
```

The odd thing is that this doesn't happen when I don't parallelize, i.e. loop through `helperFunction` manually. I'm pretty sure that I'm opening the right `Parameters` (and not the parent class).

I know it is tough to debug things without a reproducible example, I don't expect any solutions on this part. Perhaps the more general question is:

#### What does one have to pay attention to when parallelizing code that uses `pickle.dump()` via another module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

> **12.1.4. What can be pickled and unpickled? The following types can be pickled:**
>
> - None, True, and False
> - integers, floating point numbers, complex
> - strings, bytes, bytearrays
> - tuples, lists, sets, and
> - dictionaries containing only picklable objects functions defined at the top level of a module (using def, not lambda)
> - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> - instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or the result of calling `__getstate__()` is picklable (see section Pickling Class Instances for details).

Everything else can't be pickled. In your case, though it's very hard to say given the excerpt of your code, I believe the problem is that the class `Parameters` is not defined at the top level of the module, hence its instances can't be pickled.

The whole point of using `pathos.multiprocessing` (or its actively developing fork `multiprocess`) instead of the built-in `multiprocessing` is to avoid `pickle`, because there are far too many things the later can't dump. `pathos.multiprocessing` and `multiprocess` use `dill` instead of `pickle`. And if you want to debug a worker, you can use [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html).

**NOTE** As Mike McKerns (the main contributor of `multiprocess`) rightfully noticed, there are cases that even `dill` can't handle, though it will be hard to formulate some universal rules on that matter.

Comment: This answer is ok, but a little unclear.  I agree that if the OP uses `dill` instead of `pickle` for the `dump` inside the class, then there's a better chance of the object pickling, and also, yes `dill.detect.trace` can shed light on the object hierarchy that is being pickled.  There are some cases that even `dill` cannot handle yet, and sometimes things like instances of classes defined across non-installed multi-module user scripts can cause `dill` to barf.  I'd also suggest the OP try some of the other pickling variants by modifying `dill.settings`, or alternately try `cloudpickle`.